# Driver related issue

Tags: jdbc, mariadb

I am getting this issue in response  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

I am using ("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver") this in my code as my database is created in MySQL in local.

But during deployment, my Virtual Machine has MariaDB in it.

Is MySql JDBC Driver is compatible with MariaDB? Or I need to use MariaDB driver instead of JDBC MySql Driver

Comment: try with `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` and check, if you are using mariaDB driver then url will be `jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1/<db-name>`

Comment: two options to try `Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user_database","*****","*****");` with `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and second option `Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mariadb://127.0.0.1/user_database","*****","*****")` with `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` url

Comment: If you are using the MariaDB driver, you shouldn't hardcode the MySQL Connector/J driver name. Either make it configurable, or try to rely on the automatic driver loading, or better yet: use a `DataSource` instead of `DriverManager`.